# How do I get System.Rev to show in an Excel TFS-linked table?

Tags: excel, tfs, tfs-workitem

The TFS **Rev** field (**System.Rev**) shows up fine in my VS Work Item Query "Choose Columns" dialog and in the results grid. I export this query to Excel (creating an Excel TFS-linked table) and I see all other fields EXCEPT **Rev**.

I tried explicitly adding Rev to the Requirements WIT definition form so it would be present. That fixed access to a custom field, but no change to Rev field.

Configurations tried:

- PASS: TFS2010 + VS2010, VS2012 - VS works just as expected (Rev works like other fields).
- PASS: TWA (TFS Web Access 2010) shows Rev field just fine.
- **FAIL:** Excel2013, Excel2010 (each on different computer) - Both don't show Rev field in "Choose Column" dialog nor in the table generated. Other fields are fine.
- **FAIL:** SmartWord4TFS + Word2013 - Rev field missing. Other fields are fine.

I've searched for a long time with absolutely zero hits for Rev or "System.Rev" being a special case in Excel or other Office plug-ins. Please enlighten me! :-).

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem with my TFS2015+Excel 2013. I already submitted one feedback on the Microsoft Connect site, hope we can get some help there: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1893312

Comment: This feature is by design, check link in my above reply for the details.